# Why does text recognition work on the command line but not in Python's postgres function?

Tags: python, postgresql, speech-recognition, wav

I have typical speech_recognition in google, and it works properly on my server in command line python 3 -- Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0] on Linux.

In command line it works well, for example:

```
>>> import speech_recognition as sr
>>> r = sr.Recognizer()
>>> with sr.AudioFile('/var/boot/pcm.wav') as source:
...     a=r.record(source)
...     tt=r.recognize_google(a)
...     print(tt)
... 
therapy in motion giving challenge
>>>
```

But I'd need to run it in Postgres function plpython3u, global for another case plpython3u works well, for example Polly AWS python version application.

My not working code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ivr.boot_action1_pyhon(name_file character varying)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $function$

import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('/var/boot/pcm.wav') as source:
    a=r.record(source)
    tt=r.recognize_google(a)
    print(tt)

return tt
$function$
;
```

Result problem is:

```
SQL Error [38000]: BŁĄD: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
  Gdzie: Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 7, in <module>
    tt=r.recognize_google(a)
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 827, in recognize_google
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 444, in get_flac_data
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 1182, in get_flac_converter
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 1216, in shutil_which
funkcja PL/Python "boot_action1_pyhon"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is so irreproducible it's hopeless to answer. Nonetheless, here are some of my guesses.

First, do some `print (sys.version)`, then `print(sr.__version__)`, make sure that you can re-create a local enviroment matching those.

Another thing is that `a` seems to be `None`. Check for that. Make sure the file `/var/boot/pcm.wav` exists using `os.path.exists('/var/boot/pcm.wav')`

---

After a closer inspection of the traceback we can see

```
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 1182, in get_flac_converter
  PL/Python function "boot_action1_pyhon", line 1216, in shutil_which
```

that it tries to find a flac converter executable and fails at `shutil_which` -- presumably a wrapper around `shutil.which` that is equivalent to `sh` `which`. I couldn't find the source code of the `recognize_google`, so the only thing left is guess-debug this: you need some flac libraries installed on your system.

**TROUBLESHOOT**

1. find out what flac library they're using
2. make sure in the command line `which your_flac_converter` returns something
3. make sure in python `shutil.which('your_flac_converter')`

(If you're not familiar with `which`/`shutil` do some experiments first: try `which sh` or `which firefox` in the terminal, then reproduce using python's `shutil.which`)

Comment: Sir .. Thx for fast answer... path and file is ok .. azure with another code works in this python well. second this te same path and file in command line python3 works well too. after clone this situation to another serwer everything is the same error code the same .. :-(    PostgreSQL 11.9 (Debian 11.9-0+deb10u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit.  ////// Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: second a=r.record(source) pint value (a).----<speech_recognition.AudioData object at 0x7f5e80eec5f8> --- looks not none problem.....in my opinion is in  is in line tt = r.recognize_google(a)